# Android Asynctask and instance variable interaction

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, thread-safety

Lets say I have a class like below;

```
class X {
 private List<String> listing;

   class XAsync extends AsyncTask... {
      <normal async task class>
       doInBackground {
          listing = <populating from a web service>
       }
   }

   public redirectList() {

     while(listing.size == 0) {
        continue;
     }
     redirect(listing);
   }
}
```

How to make sure that listing parameter sending within redirect method is populated successfully from async task? Making sure that listing is populated with while clause is a best practice or not?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you thinking that you might need that `while` loop? That is, why can't you just do your `redirect(listing);` call at the end of `doInBackground()`, or in `onPostExecute()`?

Comment: @MikeM.you are right, I am just asking which is a good practice or not in terms of cpu ram etc.

Comment: Well, in general, loops like that are usually unnecessary, especially in event-driven programming, at the level we're at here. In this particular case, there's no need to have that loop constantly spinning during the download if you can just execute that "redirect" after it's done, instead. It's basically just wasting resources.

Comment: @MikeM. what if I had to use thread instead of asynctask there. Is it still not a good practice?

Comment: Same thing, pretty much. `AsyncTask` is basically just a "wrapper" around `Thread` already. If you would want to handle that separate `Thread` yourself directly, the same idea applies; just execute the next step when the `Thread`'s work is done. No need to have another `Thread` constantly monitoring it.

Comment: I should also point out that the given setup probably wouldn't work as you're wanting, anyway. As soon as `listing` has one item in it, your `redirect()` would fire, even though the download might not be done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the value to be put in `listing` from `doInBackground`, and then use it in [`onPostExecute`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#onPostExecute(Result)).  That is, your `redirect(listing);` call should be in `onPostExecute`, and then you won't have any need for that while loop.